Typescript resolve type
I want to resolve type using typescript library. I want the type to be displayed as
type typeCheck = {
 name: string
} 

I am not able to find the exact typeChecker function that typescript library has to get the results.
I am using the below code but unable to get the resolved type result.
const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
resolvedType = typeChecker.typeToString(type); // Pick<student, "name">


